# Ruby equivalent of foo in [one, two, three]?

Tags: ruby

Python has really elegant syntax for checking a value against several patterns.

```
2 in [1,2,4] #=> True
6 in [1,2,4] #=> False
```

Order in Ruby version just feels wrong:

```
[1,2,4].include?(2)
```

I understand that `include?` makes a lot more OO sense than `2.included_in?([1,2,4])`, I still don't like it. Ruby even has `in` keyword but it seems to only be used in construct `for i in [1,2,4]`, not for membership tests.

Another way is this:

```
(case 2 when 1,2,4 then true end)
```

Quite verbose, but allows patterns test:

```
(case file_name when "README", /\.txt\z/ then true end)
```

Still not very readable.

Am I missing some really nifty way by chance?

Comment: [1,2,4].include?(2) seems completely english to me(and works for me) ... but that's the problem not everybody likes english. do u?

Comment: You should be able to implement your own `2.in [1,2,4]` pretty easily. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ gem install sane

$ irb

```
 >> 3.in? [1,2,3]
 >> true
```

Answer (score 7):

As @deceze says, you can implement your own:

```
class Object
  def in(ar)
    ar.include? self
  end
end

irb(main):013:0> 's'.in ['a', 'b', 'c']
=> false
irb(main):014:0> 's'.in ['a', 'b', 'c', 's']
=> true
irb(main):015:0> 5.0.in [3.2, 5.0, 1.2]
=> true
irb(main):016:0> 4.0.in [3.2, 5.0, 1.2]
=> false
```

Comment: Just a small suggestion: the method should be named `in?`, which is kind of a convention for Ruby methods returning boolean values.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that the benefit of introducing "more common" pattern was not worth burdening the language with a new syntax construct with very specific use, especially because using `.include?` is neither tedious, nor counter-intuitive, when you think of it.

On the other hand, what prevents you from implementing and using `Object#included_in?` method?